# Overflow and resize issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, overflow

I have an issue with my web page.

Basically, I have the `<html>` on `overflow:hidden`, two horizontal navbars, one fixed vertical sidebar on the left and in the remaining center, one div that has the `height: 90%` property.

**Edit:** The container div has the `overflow: auto` property.

The content is loaded in the container area via AJAX. The content consists mainly of tabular data, and the point is to have the container area scroll whenever there is too much content. Everything works nice and fine on a regular monitor with normal height, but when it's taken to a laptop, the last 1-2 rows become 'hidden' due to html overflow.

If i decrease the original `height: 90%` to a smaller value, problem fixed, but after I switch to large screen with the decreased height, the content area is not fully covered.

Is there a way to fix this issue via CSS? If not, is it possible via screen resize javascript event?

Comment: Could you recreate the problem in jsFiddle or jsBin so we can have a look?

Comment: show your code, so we can try to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and probably the fastest way to do it would be using Javascript.
If you specifically set the height of your tabular data container, you will gain much more control over the layout and general item spacings.

When setting your height, you have to take into account the heights of your navbars, so in jQuery the code would look something like this:

```
function resizeMain()
{
    $('#tabularBox').height($(window).height() - $('#topBar').height() - $('#bottomBar').height());
}

// size it on load:
$(function(){
    resizeMain();
}

// and size it on resize
$(window).resize(resizeMain);
```

Of course, many ways to optimize this, but that's the idea. And you have to watchout for tiny screens, but this would be a problem with % anyway.

Finally, you need **Overflow: auto;** on our tabular box

Comment: I've edited my inital post mentioning that I use the overflow: auto property on the container. Will give that function a try.

Comment: Thank you, kind person. That solved my problem. May the spirits watch over you. :)

Answer (score 0):

in the div that is height:90% put overflow: auto or overflow: scroll. That'll add a scroll bar to that div only.